# selenium web driver double click (or select a value like ctrl+a) in a nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver and want to override a value that already exists in the datepicker textbox. I used :

```
 var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

 driver.findElement(By.css('#fromDate')).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.css('#fromDate')).sendKeys(dateStr);
```

to send the date to the input but it is not working. I want to select the date that is already in datepicker box and override with already existing datepicker value.

Comment: show us relevant html code, it's better to with page UI screenshot

Comment: thanks a lot! i fixed it by setting value to "value" attribute of input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a doubleclick  through the selenium-webdriver actions() method

```
let fromdate = driver.findElement(By.css('#fromDate'))
driver.actions().doubleClick(fromdate).perform()
```