# Double Click Calendar with Selenium NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOtxu.jpg  <-- Calendar Image

I have a calendar that requires a double click select dates. I'm working in Javascript, and the NodeJS Selenium-webdriver library has a pretty limited set of events, with no double click option... Do I need to incorporate another library for a double click feature or something? I've really hit a wall.

I know this code doesn't work, I've tried a little bit of everything. I just need to double click on a list of elements like the one below.

```
`el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='container']//table[2]//tbody[1]//tr[1]//td[3]"));

el.click()
.then(_ => driver.sleep(250))
.then(_ => el.click())
`
```

I can see the clicks happening, so I know I have the element right and the event is happening at the right place/time... but I can't trigger the "selected" dates with what I've got.

Comment: images are not good way to show what exactly you doing, or trying to achieve, always add HTML snip so other can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of some case (specific to browsers) this might not work for calendars. You might need to use javascript executer for this purpose. Below is some code for your reference.

```
    let ele = document.evaluate("//th[@title='Chrome']", document, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('dblclick', true, true);
    ele.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

This should simulate double click on the element. Store this script in a variable (e.g. scrpit) and send to browser for execution using js executor. below is some sample code assuming variable `script` has the js script

```
    driver.executeScript(script).then(function(return_value) {
       console.log('returned ', return_value)
    });
```

Comment: This was the magic. Here's my working code            
                                                                                                                     `var el = 'let ele=document.evaluate("//div[@class=\'container\']//table[2]//tbody[1]//tr[1]//td[3]",document,null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;var clickEvent=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");clickEvent.initEvent("dblclick",!0,!0),ele.dispatchEvent(clickEvent); `   `driver.executeScript(el).then(function(return_value) {
            console.log('returned ', return_value)
            })`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `actions()` method as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286755/selenium-web-driver-double-click-or-select-a-value-like-ctrla-in-a-nodejs) question's answer.

```
driver.actions().doubleClick(el).perform();
```

Comment: I did try that, but I get this error right at that line:   UnknownCommandError: POST /session/3c399601-a7fb-4867-8903-bf01c13e420c/moveto did not match a known command
      at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\Users\davek\Desktop\Projects\Selenium_test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:514:15)